# How to set "app.locale" by Session in every Request in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-middleware, laravel-localization

I am developing a localization in Laravel 10. When I triggered to change the flag of Localization Then Error Show in Page.

Can anyone tell Just where is the problem ?

---

Error Message

**Call to undefined method App\Http\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware::setLanguage() in Localization**

---

Here is my `LocalizationController` Controller

```
    {
        App::setLocale($locale);
        Session::put('locale', $locale);

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Here is my `LocalizationMiddleware`

```
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // Set Locale in this Middleware
        App::setLocale(session()->get('selected_language') ?? 'en');

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}',[LocalizationMiddleware::class, 'setLanguage'])->name('locale');
```

And here is my Blade code

```
<div class="dropdown ms-1 topbar-head-dropdown header-item">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-topbar btn-ghost-secondary rounded-circle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img id="header-lang-img" src="{{ asset('/') }}els/images/flags/us.svg" alt="Header Language" height="20" class="rounded">
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                        <!-- English language -->
                        <a href="locale/en" class="dropdown-item notify-item language py-2" data-lang="en" title="English">
                            <img src="{{ asset('/') }}els/images/flags/us.svg" alt="user-image" class="me-2 rounded" height="18">
                            <span class="align-middle">English</span>
                        </a>
                        <!-- German Language -->
                        <a href="{{ url('locale/de') }}" class="dropdown-item notify-item language" data-lang="gr" title="German">
                            <img src="{{ asset('/') }}els/images/flags/germany.svg" alt="user-image" class="me-2 rounded" height="18"> <span class="align-middle">Deutsche</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I don't understand why is this happening.

Answer (score 2):

I see some confusion regarding the use of different modules: **Middleware**, **Controller**

### Middleware

**The Middleware runs before the task associated with the route is executed.**. This includes starting a `Session` or checking authentication for an `/admin` route.

### Controller

**The Controller is the last thing that runs when a route is called.** For example, displaying a blade, saving a record in the database, querying some data, etc.

[image]

### Setting the Language

Now, let's focus on the original problem: **you want to set the language so that the appropriate language content is loaded on the website**.

**You want the page to switch to English when a link like `/locale/en` is called**. So, you want **to do this after the link is called**: using a **Controller is recommended**.

You can pass variables to the Controller, so you can also pass the language.

**app/Http/Controllers/LocalizationController.php**

```php
// ...

class LocalizationController extends Controller
{
    public function setLanguage (Request $request)
    {
         // Save selected Locale to current "Session"
         $locale = $request->locale ?? 'en';
         // App::setLocale($locale); --> There is no need for this here, as the middleware will run after the redirect() where it has already been set.
         $request->session()->put('locale', $locale);

         return redirect()->back();
     }
}
```

Then in the route, you need to call the `setLanguage` function of `LocalizationController::class` and pass the language.

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::get(
    'locale/{locale}',
    [LocalizationController::class, 'setLanguage']
)->name('locale');
```

If you want to solve it with middleware, you won't have the opportunity to pass such variables. You need to know that the set language is `en` from somewhere. It's a good idea to save the set language in the session because you can access the stored values in the middleware. However, be careful in the future not to look for the selected language as `selected_language` if you saved it as `locale` before.

**app/Http/Middlewares/LocalizationMiddleware.php**

```php
// ...

class LocalizationMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        // Set Locale in this "Request"
        $locale = $request->session()->get('locale') ?? 'en';
        app()->setLocale($locale);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**How can you set a middleware to run for a specific route in Laravel?**

By default, all middleware specified in the `web` middleware group declared in `app/Http/Kernel.php` will run for every route. (Why? See `boot()` function in `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`, where we load `routes/web.php`)
So, you need to add your own `LocalizationMiddleware` to the `web` group as follows:

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\LocalizationMiddleware::class,
    ],
    // ...
];
```

### Summary

How will the code run?

1. By default, there is no language set, so every route where `LocalizationMiddleware` is set will prioritize English language (see code).
2. I choose the German language: `de`, in reality, I called the `/locale/de` route, which triggered the `LocalizationController` `setLanguage` function. In my session, the value of the `locale` key was set to `de`, and at the end of the function, I was redirected back to the previous link. So, as a user, I didn't notice anything.
3. Due to the redirection, the previous link (from where I called the language change) is reloaded, but now the `LocalizationMiddleware` runs again where the value associated with the `locale` key is `de`, so the middleware overrides the default language to German, and finally, the content is loaded in German from the `/lang` folder.

### Extra

If you store the language in a cookie instead of a session, the next time you visit the page, it will be loaded based on the selected language.

The session is deleted after X time of inactivity. (It is configured in `config/session.php` in `lifetime` and deleted by default after 2 hours)

Comment: Thanks @rozsazoltan , From your explained, I learned a lot. Though It's not working. I am checking where is issues.

Comment: The first phase of your testing should be to check the value of session.locale by printing it out on the blade! This way, when you switch languages, you can verify whether the Session correctly modifies the configuration. It is also good to print out the value corresponding to the locale key stored in the Session itself.

Comment: For example: {{ config("session.locale") }} for the currently modified value by Middleware; {{ Session::get("locale", "no set yet") }} for the value stored by the Controller (which does not exist until the first modification, so you can handle the default value in the Middleware: ?? "en", which I set to English).

Comment: I just get the locale value from controller like this  
`$request->session()->put('locale', $locale); `
Now It's Working fine. Anyway Thanks!

Comment: @MaheKarim, Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

In your route, it should be LocalizationController instead. Try:

```
Route::get('locale/{locale}',[LocalizationController::class, 'setLanguage'])->name('locale');
```

Comment: I think it's same with my route

Comment: Not entirely. I also inserted the path mentioned by @KhangTran. I suggest checking whether you modified it correctly! In short, we usually call a function of a controller from a route. However, in your original example, you called "Localization**Middleware**". This needs to be modified to "Localization**Controller**".

Comment: Oh I See, It was mistaken when i paste here. Thanks!